# Search for specific string inside column field

Tags: sql, sql-server

In my table for specific column values are stored in three diffrent ways as shown below. It could be either one, two or three items separated by commas (of course if more than one value). Minimum is one value, maximum 3 values separated by commas. To be clear i know it's bad approach it was done (not by me) however i have to work on this and i have to change just only this query. Example showing three ways of storing values:

```
MaterialAttributes  (column name)
----------------------------------
1,12,32
3,1
9
```

I have specific sql query for searching if some value existing within field. It is universal to check all tree ways.

```
somevalue1
```

or:

```
somevalue1,somevalue2
```

or:

```
somevalue1,somevalue2,somevalue3
```

Therefore for instance if i search entire table for each row in that column to get records where `somevalue2` appears this query correctly gives me correct result.

**This is the query:**

```
";WITH spacesdeleted (vater, matatt) as (SELECT vater, REPLACE(MaterialAttributes, ' ', '') MaterialAttributes FROM myTable),
matattrfiltered (vat) as (SELECT vater FROM spacesdeleted WHERE matatt = @matAttrId
          OR matatt LIKE @matAttrId +',%'
          OR matatt LIKE '%,'+@matAttrId
          OR matatt LIKE '%,'+@matAttrId+',%' ),
dictinctVaters (disc_vats) as (SELECT distinct(vat) FROM matattrfiltered)
SELECT ID from T_Artikel WHERE Vater IN (SELECT disc_vats FROM dictinctVaters)"
```

**Note:** For security reasons if for some reasons there are spaces close to commas there will be removed (just information from other developer).

**What is the question:**
The problem now is that logic changed in the way there could be instead of 3 (max) - 12 to store in that column.

Comment: Yes, normalize your table. You create a new table where you store just the values with an FK to the original table and when selecting just do an inner join.

Comment: @JorgeCampos I would love to do that however it's not perfect world i would say. There is no possibility to do so, application and database is huge i have to work the way it is and request is to prepare new query.

Comment: No matter how huge the application is it is better to start sooner. Talk to your manager explain the situation. To add that logic to such wrong storing way will make you and the application more headaches then fixing it in a proper manner.

Comment: @JorgeCampos Already talked (no time). As i said i need to build new query based on this one, no other approach. Appreciate any help as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
                    OR matatt LIKE @matAttrId +',%' 
                    OR matatt LIKE @matAttrId +',%'
```

These are the same, should one be '%,' + @matAttrId?

Regardless, I think there's only 4 cases you need:

```
 = @matAttrId
 LIKE @matAttrId + ',%'
 LIKE '%,' +@matAttrId
 LIKE '%,' +@matAttrId + ',%'
```

Covering

> 1. single value, equals
> 2. value is start of list
> 3. value is end of list
> 4. value is in middle of list

Which is what your original query already has.

Comment: Sorry i just make typo - you right. I think no because if in the middle somewhere will be like this: 1,2,3,444,54 . In this case when i pass value 44 this wrongly will take record... (because of 444) am i right?

Comment: No: `LIKE '%,' +@matAttrId + ',%'` should match any substring that is `,44,` because of the commas.

Comment: Does it mean that what i have is really enough? P.S Note that same value could appear more than one time like: 1,2,6,44,2,7,44 as you see 44 appears two time in this case record also will be taken right?

Comment: Yes, this will work. Having the same value in the string multiple times will not matter - and having any number of values in the string will not matter. The thing that will break it would be any spaces around the numbers, because it checks for ",44," not ", 44," for example.

Comment: Yes but as you can see i remove spaces... Is it enough? Therefore that would mean what i have currently is just enough.

Comment: can you confirm whether my removing spaces solution is also just enough? Sumarizing no changes to my code?

Comment: I think so, based on no spaces.

Comment: ye but does my oryginal code whcih removes spaces really remove all spaces correctly before searching? Whant just to makre sure i didnt dismiss something.

Comment: What does your testing show?  Also note that if your spacing stuff is broken your old query is broken then too.

Answer (score 0):

You can search with

```
WHERE ',' + matatt + ',' LIKE '%,' + @matAttrId + ',%'
```

It works like this: `matatt` is extended to look like this

```
,1,12,32,
,3,1,
,9,
```

Now you can always serach for an id looking like `,id,` by using the search pattern `%,id,%`, where `id` is the real id.

This works for any number of values per column.

Comment: I am considering to leave current query according to Joe nothing to be changed, do you also think my current query do the job itself without any change?

Comment: Why keep a more complicated where clause limited to max. 3 values when there is a simpler, more robust one.